# typescript - array of instanceof

Tags: typescript, inheritance

was wondering if there is any way for typescript to realise the type of the object by deriving it from the base control descendants

```
interface Config {
  name: string;
}

interface Input extends Config {
  placeholder?: string;
}

interface Select extends Config {
  options: Array<Option>;
}

const fields: Array<Config> = [
  { name: 'a', placeholder: 'a'}, // placeholder does not exist in type 'config'
  { name: 'b', options: []} // options does not exist in type 'config'
]
```

also attempted something like

```
interface Config<T> {
  name: string;
  fieldType: T
}

interface Input extends Config<'input'> {
  placeholder?: string;
}
```

can anyone redirect?

Comment: Can you show your use case?  Why do you need to annotate `fields` at all?  You can write `const fields = [ {name: 'a', placeholder: 'a'}, {name: 'b', options: []} ]` and get an object which will be accepted by anything that requires a value of type `Array<Config>`.  Do you need to guarantee that each element of `fields` conforms to one of your declared extensions of `Config`?  If so, you'll need a union of those types somewhere in your code, which is what [@ThomasThiebaud's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58609069/2887218) suggests, but you say you want to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enforce strong typing for all individual elements in `fields`, while keeping its `Array<Config>` type, this would be a good place for type assertions.

```
const fields: Array<Config> = [
  { name: 'a', placeholder: 'a'} as Input, 
  { name: 'b', options: [] } as Select,
  { name: 'a', placeholder: 42} as Input,  // error: placeholder has number
   {options: []} as Select // error: name is missing
]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsQ2Ac2QbwFgAoZZEOAWwgC5kBnMKUHAbhIF8STRJZEUASRAAHAK5hkEAB6QQAE3ppM2PEVLIRAGwEALdFvnQA-HUbMQbTt2JgAniJQB5EWGCZkAXgJdivaPBIyADKEFoQCJIycorKWLgEJGToru4g9HQAglBQcHYAPC5umAB87MS+JAiYjMjYYYpZOXn5GPE4JV7IANpJBORUtMgA5HDDADSaOkj6htB0o8PIHMhwSsLiYON9+APUCwBGE8gpxel03QC6y6tKoeGR2xq7FPsjY5PaegZGUHQALAAmG5rZAbCSTZAAeihUhy6D+U2+cygyF0oJAYkoB2gOxOqRqF2uK1B9wikhhcKgCLorxQwCUlAZ9BYJEuQA)

Comment: Type assertions would allow `{name: 'a'} as Input`, though, which is probably not ideal.

Comment: I think this is it... as obviously I can't really ask typescript to find a matching descendant without specifically declaring it, as @ThomasThiebaud suggested.
otherwise it will scan the whole universe. which maybe should be a feature sometime. this one is accepted because it allows dynamic integration as well, without strong typing all of the current available types.

Comment: hm not sure, what you mean exactly, as `placeholder` is an optional property of `Input`. So I would consider `{name: 'a'}` as assignable to `Input`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve that is to use

```
const fields: Array<Select | Input> = [
  { name: 'a', placeholder: 'a'},
  { name: 'b', options: []}
]
```

It allows you to correctly use the parent type `Config` like that later on

```
function displayName(config: Config) {
  console.log(config.name)
}

fields.forEach(config => displayName(config))
```

Comment: tried to avoid this for the case of dozens of descendants... gonna have to declare a `type ConfigDescendats = Input | Select | TextArea | AnyOtherExtended`
Was hoping to be exposed to some kind of a built-in annotation like the `Partial<Type>`.. maybe `InstanceOf<Config>`

Comment: but thanks.. the loss of hope had me do exactly this while adding `fieldType: FIELD_TYPES` to `Config`
and a specification of the `fieldType` in every of the descendants: `Input { fieldType: FIELD_TYPES.INPUT, placeholder?: string }; so that typescript now exposes the correct allowed fields based on the `fieldType`